# Communicating web with vc++ application

Tags: string, visual-c++, web, communication, send

Today I come with a question about communication protocols between web browser (perhaps scripting) and a running vc++ application (MFC).

At first I tried to implement a solution with tcp sockets (winsock) between node.js and the application. It works actually well but I didnt know you **can't use tcp sockets on a browser** (the script has to be put in a web).

My javascript file looks like this, it is quite simple:

```
var net = require('net');

var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(4445, '127.0.0.1', function() {
    console.log('Connected');
    client.write('A');
    client.destroy();
});
```

The problem is I just want to send a string to the application, simple as that (unidirectional). Im looking into winhttp but it looks quite complex for sending a simple string.

As everything is running locally, my guess is it cannot be so hard to do it.

Any help is really appretiated, I just need a direction on which to go.

Thank you, cheers.

Comment: I suggest to start working from this sample here: https://winsockwebsocket.codeplex.com

Comment: Finally solved this, however it's a workaround that works just fine for me. I use web sockets to send a connection handshake (firefox and chrome implement web sockets natively), only the handshake has a string you share with the reciever which is the protocol, I use this string to put there what I want to send. Then the app tries to recieve via tcp socket on the same port, it fills a buffer with a whole lot of info which was created by encapsulating tcp into http, I simply remove everything until I get the string I sent. And thats it. Simple workaround.